# How to fix custom watch face time on Sony SmartWatch 2 after SW2 update

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

**Background**

Sony released an update for the Sony SmartWatch 2 in December 2014. **Whilst the update has added new features to the watch, it has unfortunately caused custom watchfaces to break.** I have developed over 100 custom watchfaces which are no longer showing the correct time (hours are out but minutes are ok) and are no longer showing dates. There is a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27641115/2777098) to the similar problem as well.

I have based my watchface code on the samples provided by Sony however I want to know if there has been a recent change to the API which requires me to recode my watchface.

I am currently utilising the following code to draw the hour hands of my watchface:

```
<com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.widget.TimeView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/hour_border_00"
    widgets:timeType="hours_fine" />
```

within a TimeLayout in my layout XML for the hour hand of my analog watchface.

**Question**

Is there something wrong with my implementation of the analog hour hand from the Sony SmartWatch 2 APIs? If so, how can I best correct it?

Comment: Nothing is unclear in the question. Check out the latest reviews on the Play store and you'll see that everybody is complaining about the same problem. Maybe their explanations will be more understandable for you.