# Sony SmartWatch 2 custom watch faces broken since firmware update

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I know this is going to be a duplicate of this -> [How to fix custom watch face time on Sony SmartWatch 2 after SW2 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536415/how-to-fix-custom-watch-face-time-on-sony-smartwatch-2-with-latest-december-sw2)

But posting because the original question got closed due to reasons that are not clear to me.

**Background**

I have an app in Google Play ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.epix.smartextension.watchfaces ) which provides custom watch faces for Sony SmartWatch 2. It's been there in the store close to an year and was doing well.

**Problem**

Recently Sony rolled out a firmware update for SW2. After this update it did bring some welcome features. But along with it came serious bugs. Main problem was that it made all the third 
party custom watch faces (including mine) meaningless. That is after this update the custom watch faces started showing wrong time, date etc..

**What I tried**

I double checked my code with the latest documentation and sample code from Sony. I'm sure the problem is not with my code as it was working fine all these months before the firmware update. Also I couldn't find any official info whether there's any new changes in watch face API or something like that. 
I also reached out to Sony developer support over email. They've assured that the issue has been reported to their team and directed me to post a query regarding the same here in stackoverflow. Hence I'm posting this.

**Question**

1. Does anyone know any work around for this?
2. Does anyone know about any changes in watch face API with the latest firmware?
3. Does anyone know whether Sony has accepted this as a bug in the latest firmware?

Any info in this regard will help a lot. 
My app had started to get bad reviews in the store recently and is finding it hard to convince the users about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have just released an update today to fix this problem. I actually tried out your app after the update and it is giving the correct time now. Give the update a try and let me know if you are still having issues.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can only answer part of the first question. I've been working with an analog watch face of my own, and I found that the minutes hand is working fine, but the hour hand is consistently wrong. Furthermore, I found that the reason it's wrong is that the hour hand starts at 12:00 from the time you download it and continues from there. For example, if you downloaded a watch face at 3:15, the watch face would show the time as 12:15. Therefore, a workaround that I was able to find for my own personal use was to start the hour hand in the position that I wanted it. IE instead of having the image of the hour hand starting in the 12:00 position, I started it in the 7:00 position and uploaded the .apk to my device at 7:00.

I realize that this is not very helpful for your app in the Play Store, but I hope that this was useful in some way. I hope that this is fixed soon!